# Binary Neural Network Classification or Multiclass Neural Network Classification?

Tags: neural-network, multiclass-classification, binary

I am confused about the difference between a binary and multiclass neural network classification. If I am writing an algorithm that has 2 output classes (Obama or Romney), but not yes or no (so not like Obama or not Obama), then is it a binary neural network or a multi class (2 class) neural network classification?

What I do know:
A binary neural network classification outputs 1 unit. If a multi class classification neural network has k classes, then it has k outputs.

What I think:

I think it is a binary neural network classification because I am really only trying to output one thing, whether a county votes for Romney or Obama. I am confused because I thought binary was more like Romney or not Romney classification and I am not sure if that is the same as Romney or Obama. Just wanted to double check and clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are making things more confusing then they are.

**Binary**

In this case you have two possible outputs:

- Obama = 1.
- Not-Obama (who in this case can only be Romney) = 0.

**Multi-Class**

In this case you have *k* possible outputs, for example when *k = 4*:

- *k = 0*: Obama
- *k = 1*: Romney
- *k = 2*: Clinton
- *k = 3*: Bush

There are approaches to tackle multi-class classification as binary classification which are called *One-vs-rest classification* and *One-vs-one classification*, other classifiers, such as Random Forests, are able to deal with a multiclass setting in a natural way. For a brief report, see [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/aly05multiclass.pdf).